# Laravel Return Redirect Back Variables Not Working Sometimes

Tags: laravel, session, redirect, laravel-5

i have a weired problem
1 : i submit form in a.blade.php and send params to controller x
in my controller x i did some action i now i want return user to a.blade.php page with some variables such as result  by redirect back() :

```
return back()->with(['var1' => '2']);
```

in my a.blade.php i get params like as :

```
{{ Session::get('var1') }}
```

BUT Problem is  : sometimes this var1 working and show result by sometimes NOT WOrking ....